How to create an animation whenever i restart my website in javascript? (no jQuery pls)
I'm working on a plant atlas website. It uses database so some of the code is in php.
Im trying to make a transform: scale() animation whenever my website is reloaded, after hours of failing to do so, I turned to you guys.
Here's my code:
PHP and CSS:
<style>
<?php
function backgroundSet($ID){
    global $conn;
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "select image from table where plant_ID='$ID';"));
    echo "#zdj$ID{
            background-image: url('../images/subpages/".$row['image']."');
            transform: scale(0.9);
            transition: transform 1s;
        }
        #zdj$ID .load {
            transform: scale(1);
            transition: transform 1s
        }
        ";
    }
    foreach($datas as $i){
        backgroundSet($i['plant_id']);
    }
?>
</style>
<?php
function Div($ID){
    global $conn;
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "select plantName, plantName_Latin, image from table where plant_ID='$ID';"));
    echo "<div id='zdj$ID' class='obrazki'>
    <span class='Efekt'>
    <span id='name'>".$row['plantName']."</span><span id='rest'><br/>Lat.".$row['plantName_Latin']."";
    echo "</span>";
    echo "</span>";
     echo "</div>";
}
?>

Javascript:
<script type="text/javascript">
        function loadVar(ID){
            var loadZdj = document.getElementById('zdj' + ID);
            }
        
        function load(){
            var load = document.getElementsByClassName('obrazki');
            for(let i=0; i > load.length; i++;){
                loadVar(i);
                loadZdj.classList.toggle('load');
            }
        }
        load();

        
        
    </script>

PHP is fine, it generates divs based on a database, but javascript simply doesn't work.
It doesn't give off any errors tho. I hope that some good soul has a solution to my problem c:

"It doesn't give off any errors tho." - That implies to me that it's not finding any matching elements.  Because if that loop iterates, it should produce an error.  If the PHP works as expected and the problem is entirely in HTML/CSS/JS, can you update this to a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem?  At the very least, that loadVar function doesn't do anything useful.  That one line of code should just be moved to where you call the function.

loadVar isn't really doing anything. You're setting a var within that function's scope and then attempting to retrieve it in an outer scope within your loop. That's not how JS variable scope works. Use a return instead, or drop the function altogether and set your variable directly within your loop.

How is your load function being called?

@LajosArpad What do you mean?

for(let i=0; i > load.length; i++;) - i, starting with a value of 0, is not very likely to be greater than load.length, is it?

And that semi-colon here, i++;), should have caused a syntax error to begin with. Please get used to using your browser console to check for such issues.

Never mind, I misread it initially

Let's fix some of the issues:
        function loadVar(ID){
               return document.getElementById('zdj' + ID);
            }
        
        function load(){
            var load = document.getElementsByClassName('obrazki');
            for(let i=0; i < load.length; i++;){
                let loadZdj = loadVar(i);
                loadZdj.classList.toggle('load');
            }
        }

Fixed bugs:

loadVar needs to return the found element instead of assigning it to a local variable
i < load.length is the correct stop condition for your for loop, because each time your cycle checks whether that's still correct and your loop ends when the condition stops being true
You need to create the loadZdj inside the scope of the function you intend to use it at

